# Seeking World War 1 military record Antonio Alphonso Ferrari of Italy

Tags: military-records, world-war-1, italy

I am seeking any records of my grandfather who fought on the italian side in World War 1.

His name was Antonio Alphonso Ferrari.

His fathers name was Felice ferrari and his mothers name was Dorothea Caruso.

His birthdate is October 1892.